# Android Studio: how to create multiple fragment buttons that lead to their own website successfully

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I would like to be able to have an app that loads button fragments; when the user presses any button, it goes to their specific website.
I am trying to use a switch statement, it works on the first button/website but won't load other websites for their respective buttons.
I have been doing it in the onCreateView class since that is the source to switch between each button and their actions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if your logic is correct then move all your code to the onViewCreated function of fragment.  Sometime the click listener in onCreateView listener cant trigger.